# In CLI, what multiple high-level languages means

Tags: .net, programming-languages

I read a lot on `.Net Framework` on the Internet and I am not fully clear. One question I have is regarding the `CLI` (Common Language Infrastructure).

According to Wikipedia:

> The Common Language Infrastructure (CLI) is an open specification developed by Microsoft and standardized by ISO[1] and ECMA[2] that describes executable code and a runtime environment that allow **multiple high-level languages** to be used on different computer platforms without being rewritten for specific architectures. The .NET Framework and the free and open source Mono and Portable.NET are implementations of the CLI.

What does **multiple high-level languages** refers to? Is it only **.NET** languages?

Comment: Just to make two examples from Microsoft: VB.NET and F#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think multiple high-level languages refer to the languages in [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CLI_languages). All these languages allow compilation into [Common Intermediate Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).

[C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language)) is the most prominent member of the family and a remarkable member is `C# .NET`, but there are many non .NET languages that implement `CLI` (mentioned in the list from the first link).

Comment: Those others have to be conformed to CLS and CTS, right? Do they use BCL?

Comment: "a remarkable member is C# .NET" Did you mean VB.NET?